# Angular 2 error- There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" with RC4 version

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am using angular 2 forms in my application and i have created the forms based on given link.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

In this for validation and to use forms APIs, i have set the `ngModel` values like `#name="id"  #id="ngModel"` and which throws script error. But its resolved if i set  `#id="ngModel"` as `#id="ngForm"`. But for my case i have to set my model value to `ngModel`.

Below is my html page.

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #myForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="id">Employee ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.id" #name="id"  #id="ngModel" >
    <div [hidden]="id.valid || id.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      Employee ID is required
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Employee Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" #name="ngModel" required>
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      Employee ID is required
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="DOJ">DOJ</label>
    <input class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.DOJ" name="DOJ" #DOJ="ngModel"  />
    <div [hidden]="DOJ.valid || DOJ.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
      DOJ is required
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Below is my issue.

```
      EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
       There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("
         <div>
          <h1>My Form</h1>
             <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [ERROR ->]#myForm="ngModel">
             <div class="form-group>
            <label class="control-label" for="id">Employee"):AppComponent@3:34
```

I have checked with more questions and answers, most of them said to update angular2 version to `RC4` so i have updated my application to rc4 but still i am facing this issue.

Below is my ts file:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms , NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,Validators,Control,ControlGroup } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
selector: 'ej-app',    
templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
directives: [ CORE_DIRECTIVES,FORM_DIRECTIVES]  
})
  export class AppComponent {
  model = new Employees(null,'','');
    onSubmit() { alert("values submitted")}
   constructor() {
     }
     }
        export class Employees {
         constructor( public id: number,public name: string, public DOJ: String ) {  }
}
```

Comment: did you enable the new forms `disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()` and ensure you don't import forms stuff from `@angular/common`?

Comment: I have edited my question and added ts files too.Can you please check with this. In this i have imported disableDeprecatedForms,provideForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix the new and old forms module.

```
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,Validators,Control,ControlGroup } from '@angular/common';
```

imports forms stuff from `@angular/common`. If you use the new forms

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms()])
```

then use instead

```
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,Validators,Control,ControlGroup } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: I have changed like below      'import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms , NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,Validators,Control,ControlGroup } from '@angular/forms';' But now i am new script error

Comment: script error: EXCEPTION: Error in app/app.component.html:7:13
platform-browser.umd.js:1900 EXCEPTION: Error in app/app.component.html:7:13BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:1900
platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefinedBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:1900
platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:1900
platform-browser.umd.js:1900 TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at DebugAppView._View_AppCompo

Comment: `#name="id" ` should be `name="id"`

Comment: Hard to tell. Can you reproduce in Plunker?

Comment: Sorry i am new plunker. I have created the link but i am unable to make it as runnbale. Can you please check this link. I have added all requried files.http://plnkr.co/edit/90nftuu6Paa5BG0qRYtl?p=preview

Comment: You can use https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html as a template. To get files into subfolders just add the folder name as prefix to the file name like `app/my.component.ts` The template is the "live example" link at the top of https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/uk0Mw07v4KqTMYdstlIP?p=preview can u please check this

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/mwiQ2K0u3IgsbGHFFWvn?p=preview. I fixed the tag of `<my-app>` in index.html, changed `id.valid` and `id.pristine` to `empid.valid` and `empid.pristine` and added a `,` after `templateUrl` in `app.component.ts`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118976/discussion-between-sasi-dhivya-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 3):

Do not import the `FORM_DIRECTIVES` and `CORE_DIRECTIVES` because they are deprecated, instead make sure that you import the `NgForm`. You can use the following:

```
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```