# Angular 2 RC7 issue with forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Recently upgraded our app to angular 2 RC7 with @angular/forms : 2.0.0.rc-7. 
When I try to run the app, the get the following error

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("ass="form-control" [required]="document.file.name == ''"
      (change)="onFileChange($event)"  [ERROR ->]#file="ngModel"/>
```

Initially was getting the same error for ngForm, but followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734684/angular-2-errror-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel-with-rc)

I am importing `FormsModule` in app.module.ts and added it to the `@NgModule.impors`. I was importing `provideForms()` and `disableDeprecatedForms()` but removed it since it was removed in RC6.

Earlier I was able to use `FORMS_DIRECTIVES` to resolve this error , but since that has been removed in RC6 , I am facing this issue.

Code Snippet:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="^(?!\s|.*\s$).*$" [(ngModel)]="document.title" ngModel
name="title" #title="ngModel" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: is this located in a different module?

Comment: If you are using this in a component in a _feature_ module, then you need to import the `FormsModule` into _that_ module. Directives from modules are not inherited. You need to import the module into whatever module you need it.

Comment: Yes, this is part of a feature module. But there are other feature components which make use of ngForm but I dont see an error from any of them.

Comment: @peeskillet I added `FormsModule` to all the feature components that use forms. Now I am getting an error about ngFormControl

`Can't bind to 'ngFormControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
    placeholder="{{placeholder}}"
    [disabled]="disabled"
    [ERROR ->][ngFormControl]="text">
</div>`

Should I change that to ngModel?

Comment: There's no such thing as `ngFormControl` in RC7. Yeah probably change it

Comment: Changed to [ngFormControl]  ->  [formControl]

Comment: Thanks peeskillet for pointing out that directives from modules are not inherited. I had FormsModule imported in base app module but not in the submodule where I was using the form. Importing FormsModule in the child module where I was using the form helped the situation. You should post this as an answer.

Comment: I was also getting similar error when I was working on form
code:
<input ngModel name="firstname" #firstName="ngModel" (change)="log(firstName)"  type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control"/>

     error:    There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("ass="form-group">...

But it got resolved when I imported formModule
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

and added FormsModule  in imported in Module Decorator function