# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" angular4

Tags: angular

I'm facing a problem using angular 4

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" (""
>   name="fullname" type="text" required maxlength="30"
>                     [(ngModel)="model.fullname" [ERROR ->]#fullname="ngModel">

**component.html**

```
<input class="form-control" name="fullname" type="text" required maxlength="30"
 [(ngModel)="model.fullname" #fullname="ngModel">
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

import { ImageUploadModule } from 'angular2-image-upload';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AddComponent } from './add/add.component';
import { EditComponent } from './edit/edit.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AddComponent,
    EditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ImageUploadModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734684/angular-2-error-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel-with-rc4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 error- There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" with RC4 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734684/angular-2-error-there-is-no-directive-with-exportas-set-to-ngmodel-with-rc4)

Comment: imports are ok, is not the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `[(ngModel)="model.fullname"` but you are never closing the square bracket it should be `[(ngModel)]="model.fullname"`